# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context, when adding Float value

Tags: swift

In my swift code

```
var k: Float = 2.5
var t = k + .now() // error

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: t) {
   self.myFunc()
}
```

I want to start `myFunc` after 2.5 seconds.

However it shows the following error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the correct types:

```
var k: Double = 2.5
var t: DispatchTime = .now() + k
```

The `+` operator is defined as:

```
public func +(time: DispatchTime, seconds: Double) -> DispatchTime
```

There is no operator for `Float` and also note the first operand must be the time.

Comment: Thanks I understand the DispatchTIie class